# Pythonの正規表現で特定のURLにマッチさせるには？

Tags: python, python3, 正規表現

以下のif文を正規表現を用いて短くしたいのですが可能でしょうか？

この1,2を識別したいです。
1にはマッチしない、2にはマッチするようにです。
よろしくお願いします。

１
https://www.pinterest.com/r/pin/554505772865723124/4995915543595742901/4cf0b7ee262acd41d1b0176d1e3ef047f3209215e827b790dc718ca5c1ea0bf6
2
https://www.pinterest.ru/pin/555772410250147342/

```
if 'www.pinterest' in check_url and '/pin/' in check_url and '/r/' not in check_url:
```

Comment: パターンの並び順がわからないと(既に試されている)`if`文に頼るしか無いので、具体的な例のURLがあった方が回答が付きやすいと思います。

Comment: 正規表現を使う強いモチベーション（使わなければ動作しない場合があるなど）が存在するのでしょうか？そうでない場合、正規表現を使うことで可読性が落ちることを懸念します。

Comment: どのように短くしたいのかを網羅的に説明してください。そうすれば正規表現で実現可能か否かの判断が出来ます。　正規表現を用いて最も短くする方法は、すべての文字列を削除する（結果として、空文字列が得られる）というものですが、それを求めているのではないでしょうから。

Comment: 正規表現が苦手なので、もしこのif文を短くするために正規表現を使用する場合どのように書いたら良いのかというモチベーションでやっております。上記のif文はandが多いので、正規表現を使用し一つにまとめられないかという事がお聞きしたい内容です。状況説明が不十分でした。申し訳ありません。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: もう少しパターンがあると良いかもしれません（現状、 `www.pinterest.com` と `www.pinterest.ru` を区別するだけで大丈夫そうに見えます）

Comment: 質問文に挙げた例だと、「1にはマッチしない、2にはマッチする」で合っていますか？ / ドメインの`.com`や`.ru`に当たる部分は任意に置き換えても基本的に同じ内容が表示されるので、この部分を正規表現で書けばよさそうな気もします。

Comment: 「1にはマッチしない、2にはマッチする」はいそうです。

Comment: `https://www.pinterest.`までは固定でしょうか？(例えば `http://www.pinterest.`にも対応させたいとか)

Comment: httpsは固定になります。`http://www.pinterest.`になることはないと考えています。

Comment: どの部分が固定でどの部分は任意としたいのか、質問文を更新して明確にしてください。でないと質問文として完結しないので回答がつけられないと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

挙げられた二例から推測すると、例えば以下の様にできそうです。

```
pattern = 'https:\/\/www\.pinterest\.\w+\/pin\/\d+\/'
```