# 正規表現でcsvファイル内の文字列とマッチさせたい

Tags: python3, 正規表現, csv

### やりたいこと

out.csv内の各URLの二番目のハイフン以降の文字を削除したい。

### 困っていること

下記のエラーがでてしまう。どうやらタイプエラーだということはわかるが、
どういう状況のエラーなのか、解決策が不明。

```
TypeError: findall() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'
```

### python ファイル内

```
import re
import csv

with open('out.csv', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    URL = re.findall(r'^[^-]*-[^-]*')
    for URL in reader:
        print (f'{URL}')
```

### out.csv

```
https://www.abcde.com/-0w69e7e1w00-あいうえお
https://www.abcde.com/-0w69e7e9w70-かきくけこ
https://www.abcde.com/-0w08e1e0w00-さしすせそ
https://www.abcde.com/-0w69e7e1w70-たちつてと
https://www.abcde.com/-0w69e6e2w54-なにぬねの
```

Comment: `out.csv` ですが、separator(区切り文字)である `,`(カンマ)が見当たりません。各行1列のみのデータという事なのでしょうか？

Comment: それと、URL の `FQDN(Fully Qualified Domain Name)` の部分には `-`(ハイフン)を使う事が可能ですので、その正規表現では想定外の部分を取り出してしまう可能性があります。

Comment: 一行のみです。
-以降のひらがなの部分を削除したいのですが、その場合どのような正規表現でしょうか。

Comment: そうなりますと、`csv.reader()` を使う必要はなくて、`for URL in f: ...` とできます。正規表現は `r'^.+?://.+?/.*?-[^-]*'` となりますが、python の標準ライブラリである `urllib` などを利用して URL をパースする方が確実ではないかと思います。

Answer (score 1):

`re.findall`は以下の様なメソッドなので、処理対象文字列を2つ目のパラメータに指定する必要があります。エラーは、その2つ目のパラメータが指定されていないために発生しているのでしょう。

[re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/re.html#re.findall)

しかも質問のソースでは、その結果を使うことなく`csv`のデータを代入していますので、`re.findall`には意味がありません。

```
URL = re.findall(r'^[^-]*-[^-]*')
for URL in reader:
```

おそらく、本当に使いたいのはこちらの`re.compile`ではないでしょうか？
こちらならばパラメータが1つでも不思議ではありません。

[re.compile(pattern, flags=0)](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/re.html#re.compile)

これを使う場合でも、`re.compile`の結果オブジェクトを格納する変数と、csvの1行を読み取る変数は変える必要があります。
そして`for`ループの中でcompile結果オブジェクトを使って処理を行うことになります。

---

あるいは`re.findall`のまま使うなら、`csv`を`csv`としてではなく、テキストファイルとして読み込んで処理するか、`for`ループの中で`csv`の1行毎に処理するという風に変える必要があるでしょう。

---

ちなみにURLの正規表現とかは、こちらの記事が参考になると思われます。
[Pythonの正規表現で特定のURLにマッチさせるには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/53818/26370)
[python 正規表現でURLの一致チェック、抽出を行う](http://trelab.info/python/python-%E6%AD%A3%E8%A6%8F%E8%A1%A8%E7%8F%BE%E3%81%A7url%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%80%E8%87%B4%E3%83%81%E3%82%A7%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%80%81%E6%8A%BD%E5%87%BA%E3%82%92%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%86/)
[urlの正規表現におけるドメインの取得(python)](https://qa.atmarkit.co.jp/q/9605)
[Python regular expression again - match url](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6718633/9014308)
[gruber/Liberal Regex Pattern for Web URLs](https://gist.github.com/gruber/8891611)
[URLで使用可能な文字、使用できない文字](https://www.ipentec.com/document/web-url-invalid-char)
[正規表現による URLの検出](https://www.ipentec.com/document/regularexpression-url-detect)

---

取り敢えず元ソースに近く`csv`も使わない形で、ちょっと大雑把ですがこんな風になるでしょう。

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"(https?:\/\/[\w:%#$&\?\(\)~\.=\+\-]+\/-[^-,]*)-[^-,]*")

with open('out.csv', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for row in f.readlines():
        m = pattern.match(row)
        if m:
            print(m.group(1))
```

結果はこうなります。

```
https://www.abcde.com/-0w69e7e1w00
https://www.abcde.com/-0w69e7e9w70
https://www.abcde.com/-0w08e1e0w00
https://www.abcde.com/-0w69e7e1w70
https://www.abcde.com/-0w69e6e2w54
```